# Center multiple independent items in swift (storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistoryboard

I'm developing an app for iOS devices. Here's the description of my problem: [image]

As you can see, there's a label and below, three images and three labels, all independent. I need to center all of these items, is there a way to do it in storyboard? I'm familiaring with storyboard, and maybe there's a way to put the correct constraints. I have more experience on html, and there to do this I'd just put a new div wrapping all the items. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can add constraints to each of the item as i have added , i have added the image for each view and the constraints applied for each of them

Constraints explained:-

1) For the center label , i have added top constraint and centered it horizontally

2) For all the imageView i have pinned the width and height of the images you can do that as per you're requirement

3) I have aligned the top of each of the image to the labels and the labels top to the next image - so that they remain in the same horizontal line

4) Added horizontal spacing between the image and the label and also between the label and the next image so that they remain together

5) Added center horizontal constraint to the "by author" label since it is in the center and since all the other labels and images have horizontal spaces linked with each other the entire unit will stay center aligned.

6) Added a vertical spacing between the second image and the "center label"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And if you run it on any device (iPhone/ipad) it would be in center as per your requirement , i have added 2 images to show the output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try later but i'm sure that will work

Comment: Yes please do check it and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: Just tried and works as expected. Thank you very much!